# Create a web server using gsm module

Tags: raspberry-pi, gsm

I am using raspberry pi
I am using signalR to send data to my client browser.
If my raspberry  is on the same network via Ethernet or WiFi then I can get it to work.
If I now disconnect Ethernet and WiFi and switch on my gsm module I get assigned a dhcp address like 10.126.88.4 etc
If I now go to a client browser and type that ip address in the browser it will eventually time-out and upon investigation I find the raspberry pi has been assigned a different IP address.
This happens every time I refresh the browser.
After googling I find that it is the network providers doing this to stop the gsm being used as a server gateway.
One of the solutions is to use a proxy server but I could potentially have a lot of data passing through and

my initial idea was to have client browser talking directly to the raspberry pi device using gsm and thus not going through my own server.
Is there a solution to my predicament?

Comment: Could you be more specific about how the IP address gets assigned to your GMS module. Do you mean it is a public IP address by your GMS provider?

Comment: Hi yes that’s right. A public IP address

Comment: Since you probably can't get a static IP by your network provider you could instead use a dynamic DNS provider and access the GSM interface via a hostname. I've previously followed [this tutorial](http://raspberrypi.tomasgreno.cz/dyndns-client.html) and it worked just fine.

Comment: Thanks @andypotato  I shall take a look